# Proof a real functional is continuous in $C_{[a,b]}$ (verification)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I wish to have some feedback on the following proof of the claim below, either if it is correct, what to fix, or other suggestions.

Claim: Let $\psi :[0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function (or at least integrable). Then $F(x)=\int_a^b \psi(t,x(t)) \mathrm{d}t$ for any $x(t) \in C_{[a,b]}$ is a continuous functional.

Proof:
Since $\psi$ is continuous on its domain, for any $v_0 \in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$ and given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $\delta >0$ such that $|\psi(v)-\psi(v_0)|<\epsilon/(b-a)$ whenever $\rho(v,v_0)<\delta$ for all $v\in [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}$. Let $c(t) \in C_{[a,b]}$. Let $v_0=(t,c(t))$, for any $t\in [a,b]$. Then let $x(t) \in C_{[a,b]}$ and suppose $\rho_\infty(x,c) < \delta$. If $v=(t,x(t))$ then $\rho(v,v_0)=\sqrt{(t-t)^2+(x(t)-c(t))^2}=|x(t)-c(t)|\leq \rho_\infty(x,c)<\delta$ which implies $|\psi(v)-\psi(v_0)| <\epsilon/(b-a)$ i.e. $|\psi(t,x(t))-\psi(t,c(t))|<\epsilon/(b-a)$. Then, $|F(x)-F(c)|=|\int_a^b \psi(t,x(t))-\psi(t,c(t))\mathrm{d}t|\leq \int_a^b |\psi(t,x(t))-\psi(t,c(t))| \mathrm{d}t \leq \int_a^b \epsilon/(b-a) \mathrm{d}t =\epsilon$, hence $|F(x)-F(c)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to define a metric on the domain of F. You seems using $||_{\infty}$ on the domain of $F$.
2. You actually used a strong assumption on $\psi$. You need $\psi$ is uniform continuous on $[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I am sorry I meant to include it explicitly but overlooked it. The domain of $F$ is indeed $C_{[a,b]}$ with the metric induced by the uniform norm (or max norm some call it?) , $||_\infty$. I had thought continuity of $\psi$ might not be strong enough and my attempt messing around with the point $(t,c(t))$ made me think uniform continuity was necessary but I was unsure. Would the argument be similar if i make this stronger assumption? Thank you for the answer, of course!

Comment: your proof is correct if $psi$ is uniform continuous.